# $\aleph_\omega$ and large ordinals?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals, large-cardinals

Assuming the GCH, each time you take the powerset of an aleph number, the subscript increases by one. So there is $\aleph_0, \aleph_1, \aleph_2\ldots \aleph_\omega\ldots \aleph_{\epsilon_0}\ldots$ and so on.

This may be a dumb question, but how large of an ordinal has to be present in the subscript below the aleph in order for the resulting aleph number to make it onto the large cardinal hierarchy? For example, how does aleph_church-kleene compare to the smallest inaccessible cardinal?

Comment: The comment-sized answer: virtually all large cardinals are _fixed points_ of the aleph function; that is, they're 'numbers' $\kappa$ for which $\kappa = \aleph_\kappa$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term "large cardinal" [doesn't have an agreed up, concrete definition](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155558/what-is-the-definition-of-a-large-cardinal-axiom). When we say that $\kappa$ is a large cardinal we might mean that $\kappa$ is inaccessible and has additional properties; or we might mean that it has properties which imply the consistency of large cardinals.

Some people would refer to the former as large cardinals, and the latter as "large cardinal properties".

If we agree with that convention, then every large cardinal is a weakly inaccessible cardinal at least, which means that it is an $\aleph$-fixed point. Namely $\kappa=\aleph_\kappa$ (and in fact, it is the limit of fixed points, and limits of limits of fixed points and so on).

As to your second question, $\aleph_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ has only countably many $\aleph$'s below it. That's just a tiny fraction of the cardinals you will find below the *first* $\aleph$ fixed point. If $\kappa$ is inaccessible then it is the $\kappa$-th fixed point, meaning it is unfathomably larger.

Let me add a side remark, $\sf GCH$ has little to do with this. A strongly inaccessible cardinal is also a $\beth$ fixed point (with similar properties as discussed above), where $\beth$ numbers are defined using the power set operation, rather than successor cardinals.

---

**Added:**

It may be a bit misleading to think that being a large cardinal is all about having a large index as an $\aleph$ number. Being a large cardinal means having some combinatorial properties which allows you to prove more. Successor of large cardinals are not "large" themselves, because in $\sf ZFC$ successor cardinals are do not posses the basic requirement of a large cardinal, being a regular limit cardinal.

Comment: (And another tiny comment: the reason why they're fixed points is because they're _regular_ cardinals - that is, they're not the limit of a sequence $\{\kappa_\alpha\} : \alpha\lt\beta$ with 'size' ($\beta$)less than the cardinal itself; the technical name for this size, if you want to learn more about it, is the _cofinality_ of the cardinal.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, I don't follow; the least aleph fixed point is singular.

Comment: @Steven, while that is true, if $\kappa$ is inaccessible then it is the $\kappa$-th fixed point, so in particular there are plenty of fixed points below the first inaccessible, none of which are regular.

Comment: Asaf, I have a terminological question for you. Suppose $\kappa$ is a large cardinal in whatever sense we're talking about. Would you feel comfortable referring to $\kappa^+$ as a large cardinal?

Comment: @goblin: Not in the context of $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: @goblin: The point being that "large cardinal" is ultimately a combinatorial property (being a regular limit cardinal *is* a combinatorial property, to some extent). It is not as much as "being very large" in cardinality, as it is to have strong combinatorial characteristics which allow us to prove more statements.

Comment: I thought so. You should probably mentioned that in your answer. The OP writes: "how large of an ordinal has to be present in the subscript below the aleph in order for the resulting aleph number to make it onto the large cardinal hierarchy?" However this suggests a certain misunderstanding, namely that if $\aleph_\alpha$ is deemed a large cardinal, then every $\aleph_\beta > \aleph_\alpha$ is also a large cardinal.

Comment: Regarding "That's just a tiny fraction of the cardinals you will find below the *first* $\aleph$ fixed point", it's also (this for the OP, of course) just a tiny fraction of the cardinals you will find below ${\aleph}_{{\omega}_{1}}.$

Comment: Asaf and @goblin: I don't mean to suggest that fixed point -> regular, but the opposite - i.e., 'not fixed point' -> singular, since it gives us a concrete sequence witnessing that cof($\kappa$) != $\kappa$.

Comment: @Steven: For limit cardinals, sure.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro May I ask you ℵω1 is also not inaccessible cardinal right? Thanks

Comment: @PanMrož: Its cofinality is $\omega_1$, so it is singular. Therefore not inaccessible.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for your answer. May I ask you how can I "visualize" how large of a ordinal number must be in the subscript for it to be inaccesible?

Comment: @PanMrož: If $\kappa$ is [weakly inaccessible], then $\kappa=\aleph_\kappa$. Namely, there are $\kappa$ cardinals smaller than it. But here's the thing: there are actually $\kappa$ cardinals of the form $\lambda=\aleph_\lambda$ below it already. How do you visualize this? You really don't.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So much much larger then ℵω1 right?

Comment: @PanMrož: Yes. Ridiculously larger.

Comment: @AsafKaragila May I please ask you, since there is Aleph number for every ordinal (with the ordinal in the subscript) and the number of all ordinals is too big to be a set as it forms a proper class,  is an Inaccesible cardinal larger then any Aleph with ordinal in a subscript?

Comment: @PanMrož: No. An inaccessible cardinal is a cardinal, which is by definition is a set. The inaccessibility simply means that we cannot access it from "below" in any non-predicative sense (so there are no shorter sequences which are cofinal below it, and power sets operations are not helpful either). As I wrote above, explicitly, we know what is the $\aleph$-index of an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$: it's $\kappa$ itself.

Comment: @AsafKaragila so for all cardinals in Large cardinal hierarchy there is some aleph with some ordinal subscript that is larger?

Comment: @PanMrož Yes. Every cardinal has a successor.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But those large cardinals cannot be reach by iteratively taking powersets right?

Comment: @PanMrož: Yes. Just like $\omega$ cannot be reached within finite means from finite sets.

Comment: @AsafKaragila And can one go beyond cardinals such as aleph with ordinal subscript? I get that ordinals form a proper class and there is bijection between ordinals and cardinals, but is there anything beyond it? Some supremum larger than any Aleph with ordinal subscript?

Comment: @Pan: No. As I keep saying, cardinals are sets. I know, this topic is confusing, what with large cardinals and generating cardinals. My advice to you is to ignore that confusion for now. Work with the definitions, and it will help you develop some intuition, at some point. It takes hard work, but you can't win it in any other way. No matter how many times you ask me (or anyone else) variations of the same question about these topics. If you don't sit down to work with the concepts, they will never be yours to understand.

Comment: @AsafKaragila no no I get (or at least somehow) the difference between sets and classes in this case I worded it poorly. This is a hoby for me, I have bachelor degree in software engineering and am now graduate student of business school majoring in project management. I just find it fascinating (for my megalomania) finding ever larger things. And I was curious if there is anything beyond proper class (not like 2-class of all classes) but a measure of how big a set theoretical universe can be.

Comment: @Pan: Let me conclude this discussion with the following. The set theoretic universe is as big as the set theoretic universe, and no larger. You can add axioms which will let you find smaller, perhaps also "shorter", universes that *could* be universes of set theory. But once you've fixed your universe of set theory, it is fixed—if only for the current line of thought—and its size is fixed. Measuring it from the inside is possible. So you have to get a larger universe and measure it there, but that's a different story for a different time, and requires grokking the fine details of it all.

Comment: In my opinion [worldly cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worldly_cardinal) should count as large cardinals, and worldly is a weaker property than (strongly) inaccessible, and does not imply regularity. But worldly cardinals are also $\beth$ fixed points.

Comment: @Arvid: I have heard talks from professors who said that "a large cardinal is a critical point of an elementary embedding".